# php mail and sendmail hangs

Tags: sendmail, email

I'm trying to send mail via PHP's `mail()` function, but it hangs the script. I tried using sendmail on command line (CentOS 5.8) as was suggested in many posts I've read but it also hangs. This is what im putting in:

`sendmail -v myemail@mail.com < message.txt`

which says:

`myemail@mail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...`

and that's it. It hangs there.

Here are the last 2000 lines of logs from /var/log/maillog: [logs](http://pastebin.com/QMSZV4qA)

I'm clueless as to how to continue debugging this issue, please advise.

Comment: What do your logs say? /var/log/syslog, /var/log/mail.log, /var/log/mail.err ?

Comment: Ok, let's tackle the elephant in the room... Have you configured a mail server/relay on your machine?

Comment: Are you on a virtual machine? If so can you post the output of `iptables -L` ?

Comment: @BartDeVos no, I don't know how to do that or what that means. adamo I'm not on a virtual machine. Added logs to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've uninstalled sendmail and postfix and then installed postfix again. That fixed it for for me.

I did this:

```
$ yum remove sendmail
$ yum remove postfix
$ yum install postfix
$ service postfix start
```